# How to prevent "."(dot) from cancelling autocomplete in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

I have defined some keywords for a proprietary language I use at work:

```
{ "match": "\\b(util.tickettimelimit|util.user_ip|util.server_name|util.today)\\b",
  "name": "keyword.source.GTX2",
    "comment": "Tags"
}
```

I also have a completion file:

```
{
  "scope": "source.GTX2",

  "completions":
  [
    "util.server_name",
    "util.tickettimelimit",
    "util.today",
    "util.user_ip"
  ]
}
```

When I start typing "util" I see the correct autocomplete options:

[image: Autocomplete working ok]

But as soon as I enter the "."(dot) autocomplete options go away:

[image: Autocomplete not working as desired]

Is there a way to change this behavior? I just want the keywords to be trated as a whole thing and ignore the dots.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked everywhere I can, and it seems the auto-complete code is embedded within the executable itself (at least on Windows, I haven't checked my Mac yet), and not in one of the numerous external `.py` files scattered around, so I can't even see the parameters for how auto-completion is performed. I looked through the default `Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings` file and while there are several options relating to auto-complete, there are none relating to what we're looking for. While looking through the `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file in the same directory, I tried adding the following:

```
{ "keys": ["."], "command": "hide_auto_complete", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

but alas it didn't work. There are a number of `auto_complete` commands there, and while this looked the most promising I haven't tried the rest.

I haven't exhaustively looked through the source and config files for the nifty [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin (also available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)), so it's possible you might be able to find an option there. You'd probably have to completely disable the built-in auto-complete functionality first, so it doesn't override SCI.

So, I guess for now there's not much you can do. You can always leave a [feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/) and see if it makes it into [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), or search/open a thread on the [Sublime Text Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) and see if anyone else has any suggestions. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm accepting this one for the time invested :D

Comment: There is a solution to this and it is easy. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

What I think @Ashish is alluding to is the `word_separators` setting. You will want to create a syntax specific preference (`Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User`). Create a `word_separators` entry with the dot removed (Copy from the default preferences as the base). This will give you the behavior you want but there are  some things to note. The dot, obviously, will not be treated as a word separator, which will change some behavior.

I'll use java as an example. If I had a variable `foo`, with some method `bar`, I could enter `foo.b` and `bar` would be shown as a completion. Without the dot as a separator, you will not see this.

Another example, perhaps easier to understand is when selecting words. If you use ctrl/cmd + d to select the word, it selects words, bound by word separators. So if I had `foo.ba|r`, where the | represents the cursor position and used ctrl/cmd+d it would select `bar`. With the dot removed as a word separator, `foo.bar` would be selected.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late but I hope this can help, create a new plugin and add this code:

```
import re


myObjects = {"util": ["server", "tickettimelimit", "today", "user_ip"]}


class CustomAutocomplete(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        if not view.match_selector(0, "source.GTX2"):
            return

        if prefix == "":
            # get the last word in the current line
            currentposition = view.sel()[0].begin()
            currentline = view.full_line(currentposition)
            text = view.substr(currentline)
            words = re.findall("\w+", text)
            lastword = words[-1]

            if lastword in myObjects.keys():
                # return a list of tuples, it represents snippets
                # the first element is the trigger and the second one
                # is the content
                return [(x, x) for x in myObjects[lastword]]

        return []
```

And add the next key in the user settings:

```
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source.GTX2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Nice!  I've been looking for something like "auto_complete_triggers" for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Don't press . (dot) else you will need to type at least one character after dot so list can appear again. Using Brackets or Dot tells Sublime Text 2 that user has completed typing.

example: if I type `for` then sublime will show dropdown list but if I type `for(` list will disappear.

Comment: I noticed that I could do "utiltoday" for example, but If possible I would like to change the dot behavior. Is there any configuration I can look at to achieve this?

Comment: @fedxc - I've never seen any configuration options dealing with this, it might be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Preferences > Settings - User, then copy and paste the following

```
// Characters that are considered to separate words – does not include periods.
// Place comma at the end of the line if there are multiple keybindings.
"word_separators": "/\\()\"‘-:,;~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

From this webpage:
http://tomschenkjr.net/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/

Comment: this doesn't go in the key bindings, it goes in the user preferences. Additionally, the curly braces are not required.