# Trigger autocompletion on dot

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

How can I trigger autocompletion popup when I type .(dot), for Python scope for example?

---

To address @skuroda comment I'll extend the question:

Auto-complete in ST is triggered on any character pressed if `"auto_complete": true` is set in preferences (it's set by default). I find this most annoying, as I don't want it trigger on single key pressed, so I turned it off.

`html_completions.py` just checks which is previous character to current, and provides completion lists, but does not change auto-completion behavior or set what triggers it.

OTOH, there is `auto_complete_triggers` preference, but that doesn't solve the problem for me, because it depends on `auto_complete` preference:

- if `auto_complete` preference is set to false, defined trigger in `auto_complete_triggers` won't trigger completion
- if it's set to true, then again I get auto-completion on any key pressed and not just on dot like most Python aware editors do

Another acceptable solution would be if I could define some threshold, like for example 4 characters, so that auto-completion doesn't show on single key pressed automatically, but after 4 characters, as example.

Comment: It's likely not possible - see this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684193/how-to-prevent-dot-from-cancelling-autocomplete-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo. Do you perhaps know about a third party package that allows this feature? Or if this feature is somehow accessible through Python?

Comment: I don't think so, because it looks like this functionality is hard-coded, and I couldn't find anything in the API to override it. SublimeCodeIntel is a great plugin for vastly expanding the built-in autocomplete features, and I highly recommend installing it. I haven't looked completely through **its** API, as it's huge and the associated libs aren't in python, so there may be a way of doing it, but I'm not aware of it yet.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for when you enter dot. If you are looking for it to not act  as a word separator, see my answer in that issue. If you want all of the available autocomplete options to come up when you press dot, try adding an "auto_complete_trigger". See the default preferences for an example with HTML. If you are trying to get another behavior, please include more details. :)

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to change word definition for Python. I already looked in `html_completions.py` but as far as I see, it does not offer solution, and I'll add that information in question to avoid lengthy comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple plugin to get that threshold effect.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MyEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        if len(prefix) < 4:
            return ([], sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS | sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS)
        else:

            return []
```

In addition, try adding the following to the syntax specific settings (`Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User`). I believe it should give you the behavior you want with the dot operator.

```
"auto_complete_selector": "- source, comment",
"auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "source.python", "characters": "."} ]
```

I only minimally tested both solutions, so let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Thanks. Plugin solution doesn't seem to work, and I guess we know why - it just doesn't provide additional list, while it certainly doesn't overwrite ST suggestions ;) However, `"auto_complete_selector": "- source, comment"`, does exactly what I wanted :) Can you point me to some documentation about this preference or maybe tell what it did?

Comment: Hmm well the plugin should just bring up the pop up after 4 characters are inserted (with the normal ST completions). Anyways,I came across this stuff simply playing around with different settings. Unfortunately, this stuff isn't well documented. Those two settings are described in the default preferences. Sadly, that's the best way to discover how to modify things. Even some of the plugin stuff isn't well documented. I'd almost like to see a wiki with some better documentation, I'm not sure how often the unofficial docs are updated.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too. ST is so extensible, but documentation is at very low priority I guess. Hopefully a critical user mass will create some wiki, apart this SO knowledge base...